# Survey123 Connect - Limit number of decimal places

Tags: arcgis-survey123, arcgis-survey123-connect

I have a decimal field (End Mile Marker) that I'm trying to limit the number of decimal places that are being displayed in it.
The field is read-only and has a calculation (${begin_mile_marker}+0.1)

Example: when I enter the number 3.2 in "Begin Mile Marker" I get 3.30000000003 in the "End Mile Marker" field. I'd like that number to display just 3.3.

Is there a way to add a rounding function to my calculation? or maybe limit the number of decimal places for a field?

I'm using ArcGIS Survey 123 Connect.

[image: Begin and end mile marker]

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found this solution.

I modified the formula in the 'Calculate' field as follow:

round(${begin_mile_marker}+0.1, 2).

That limit that decimal place to 2 decimal places.